# C# parse error in View Model int? to int

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm currently working on an app using C# 6. I want to do a super cool trick, but unfortunately it doesn't work they way I thought, and only leads to a Null Exception, if the property is empty:

```
public string CoolId {get;set;} // e.g. 1,5,3,7

public List<int> CoolIdList => WebUtility.HtmlDecode(CoolId).Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse).ToList();
```

It works if the property CoolId has values such as "1,5,3,7" if it's empty there is a Null Exception.

If I would do

```
public List<int?> CoolIdList => WebUtility.HtmlDecode(CoolId).Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse).ToList();
```

...I get an Exception right away.

Do you know how to solve this issue?

Thanks :)

Comment: You need to figure out what you want to do if it's `null`.

Comment: int32.Parse will throw an ArgumentNullException if the parameter is null. I'm not sure if that's what you're getting though.

Comment: If you cannot rely on the property being set, then I would also suggest you cannot rely on it having a valid value either. So you should be validating more than just null values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to

1. Check for null.
2. Remove empty entries at the time of splitting.

```
WebUtility.HtmlDecode(CoolId ?? string.Empty)
          .Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Answer (score 1):

Otherwise you can implement the extension method of split which handles null string also